# How to disable the iOS 17 Autofill Popup?

Tags: ios, xamarin, autofill

Hello dear StackOverflow users,

i've encountered an annoying problem within my Xamarin.iOS app. Simply put, starting with iOS 17, a lot of my UITextFields now offer me the AutoFill function. When i tap the AutoFill button, iOS offers me to fill in contact details or a password.

Please do not confuse this with the AutoFill functionality that is available on the iOS keyboard. Everything is fine on the keyboard end.

Here's a screenshot to show the AutoFill function in question:

[image: Screenshot showing a text box with a popup offering the Autofill function]

I tried disabling the popup through the `CanPerform()` selector, however iOS does not seem to pass the AutoFill function to `CanPerform()`.

Here's my code for `CanPerform()`:

```cs
public bool EvaluateEditSelector(string selector) //gets called by CanPerformAction()
{
    if (AllowCopyPaste || CopyPasteOverride)
    {
        switch (selector)
        {
            case "cut:":
                return showCopyPaste;
            case "copy:":
                return showCopyPaste;
            case "select:":
                return showCopyPaste;
            case "selectAll:":
                return showCopyPaste;
            case "paste:":
                return showCopyPaste;
            case "makeTextWritingDirectionLeftToRight:": //Last selector
                showCopyPaste = true;
                return false;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I checked the UIMenuBuilder or rather the UIMenuIdentifiers whether there is an identifier for the AutoFill, however i haven't found a corresponding identifier.

Here's the code within `BuildMenu()`:

```cs
public override void BuildMenu(IUIMenuBuilder builder)
{
    if (Device.GetSystemVersion().Major >= 16) //helper method to check system version
    {
        builder.RemoveMenu(UIMenuIdentifierExtensions.GetConstant(UIMenuIdentifier.Lookup));
    }
    base.BuildMenu(builder);
}
```

Thank you in advance for your attention.

Comment: Do you mean [turn off the AutoFill](https://support.apple.com/en-sg/guide/iphone/iphccfb450b7/ios).

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT You may notice that my app looks quite different from Safari. This is because my app is not Safari. So Safari settings do not apply to my app.

Nevertheless i have disabled AutoFill for contacts in the Safari settings on the off-chance they did apply as well as AutoFill for passwords.

Turning both settings off did not get rid of the AutoFill function.

Comment: Did you use a custom renderer to customize the context menu?

Comment: Try using "com.apple.menu.autofill" as the identifier: `builder.RemoveMenu ("com.apple.menu.autofill");`

Comment: I have same problem in native iOS, did you find any solution for this? thanks

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
override func buildMenu(with builder: UIMenuBuilder) {
    if #available(iOS 17.0, *) {
        builder.remove(menu: .autoFill)
    }
    super.buildMenu(with: builder)
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I solved it using the method provided above;
In subclass UITextField add:

```
-(void)buildMenuWithBuilder:(id<UIMenuBuilder>)builder {
if (@available(iOS 17.0, *)) {
    [builder removeMenuForIdentifier:UIMenuAutoFill];
}
[super buildMenuWithBuilder:builder];
}
```

It's useful for me!